# CodeIgniter: Simple URL routing question

Tags: php, codeigniter, url-routing, codeigniter-routing

I'm new to CI and URI routing in general.

I created a new app. Set the default controller to `Main`. In `Main`, I have an `index` method, a `popular` method and a `recent` method.

When I load my app, the url shows up as `http://localhost/myapp`... this obviously loads up the `index` method in the `Main` controller... that's fine.

Now how do I route my URIs so I can load up the popular and recent method by going to `http://localhost/myapp/popular` and `http://localhost/myapp/recent` respectively?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use CodeIgniter's routing features. To do that, just add the following lines to your application/config/routes.php file:

```
$route['recent'] = "main/recent";
$route['popular'] = "main/popular";
```

Comment: You cannot have a controller with the name, "index". It is reserved. 

See http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/reserved_names.html

Comment: Oops. Yeah, fixed the typo. Index was supposed to be main.

Answer (score 2):

```
$route['recent'] = "your_controller/recent";
$route['popular'] = "your_controller/popular";
```

That's what you will need. Any call to "recent" will route to "your_controller/recent". The same goes with popular.

Answer (score 0):

If `popular` and `recent` are actual pages in your application, as opposed to functions, you ought to move those to their own controllers, as opposed to keeping them under main.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with CodeIgniter specifically, but that doesn't sound right at all. I'm 99% sure it's router can do this, and messing with the already configured `mod_rewrite` is probably not a good idea, nor is it consistent.